# C++ Memory allocation issue

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, memory

My code is like below:

```
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    int ii = 123;
    char str[7] = "";
    strcpy(str,"123456");
    return 0;
}
```

I run this in VS2010, the memory is like below

[image]

I am curious what the `cc` in the memory used for? And how the number of `cc` is calculated?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When compile for "Debug" in Visual Studio, the `cc`'s are often used to fill up uninitialized memory. That way it's more obvious when you access uninitialized memory.

For example, if you try to dereference an uninitialized pointer, you'll likely get something like:

```
Access Violation accessing 0xcccccccc
```

or something like that.

[image]

Comment: And why did MS choose `0xCC` as the fill value? Because `0xCC` is the single-byte breakpoint instruction in the x86 instruction set. That way, if you accidentally execute unfilled memory, it will hit a breakpoint instantly.

Comment: @Rob That I didn't know. :) I suppose it's of less relevance now that we have memory protection?

Comment: @Mysticial: not really: that only works on a page level (an entire page can be marked as executable or not, and only if the CPU, OS and process all agree to enable the NX-bit). But what if you use 40 bytes of code out of a 2KB page? The page has to be marked executable, which leaves the rest of the page executable, but containing garbage :)

Answer (score 1):

When you access the uninitialised memory space, VC2010 will always warn you that you have accessed some address containing `0xcccccccc`,

`0xcc` is the value used by the compiler (in a debug build) to fill up the uninitialized memory.